# Remove least complete duplicate rows in R or SQL

Tags: sql, r, duplicates

I have a dataset like this:

```
id_1 <- c(1, 1, 1)
id_2 <- c(2, NA, NA)
day <- c("Mon", "Mon", "Mon")
month <- c("May", NA, "May")
year <- c("2017", NA, NA)

df <- cbind(id_1, id_2, day, month, year)
```

These rows are duplicate observations in my data. I would like to keep only the most complete row (i.e. row 1). My real data has 15 columns, so using

```
duplicated(df[, <some combination of columns>])
```

seems complicated. Is there a function for this? Or some simple answer I'm overlooking? Answers in R are preferred, but SQL is also a possibility. Thank you in advance!

EDIT:
id_1 and id_2 are both identifiers for the observation. id_1 should definitely be unique in this data, but it's ok for id_2 to be NA or repeated for some rows. Eventually I will merge this data table with another data table using id_2. That's why I would like to eliminate rows that repeat information already captured by a row which includes id_2.

Comment: One option is to sum the number of `NA`s for each row and then order/dedup based on that. Assuming you want to dedupe based on `id_1` this would look something like: `df$num_complete <- rowSums(!is.na(df));
df <- df[order(-df$num_complete),];
df[!duplicated(df$id_1),]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `id_1` is an identifier for each "subject", then you could do this:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(id_1) %>%
  filter(rowSums(is.na(.)) == min(rowSums(is.na(.))))
```

Do you have situations where there are two rows with the same number of missing values, but different values are missing in each row? In that case, you might want to combine data from different rows to create a single row containing all the available data.

**UPDATE:** Per @docendodiscimus's comment, you can shorten the code as follows:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id_1) %>%
  slice(which.min(rowSums(is.na(.))))
```

Comment: what about `slice` + `which.min` on the rowSums?

Comment: This takes ages on a sizeable data set, any suggestions for a speedier alternative?

Comment: Also be warned that the `slice` solution will take the first item if it has two with the same number of `NA`s, whereas the filter solution keeps all that have the fewest `NA`s

Answer (score 1):

eipi10's solution certainly looks neater but this one is base R.

```
 df[     apply(df, 1, function(x) length(na.omit(x))) == 
    max( apply(df, 1, function(x) length(na.omit(x))) )
        ,  ]
 #---------------- 
  id_1   id_2    day  month   year 
   "1"    "2"  "Mon"  "May" "2017"
```

You didn't say that this should be done in groups of identical id1's but if you did, then eipi10's group_by would correspond to a base `lapply( split(df, df$id1) , ...function)`. I like @MikeH.'s suggestion to use `rowSums(!is.na(df))` better than my idea. Maybe he will post an answer?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I should have specified, but id_1 and id_2 are both unique identifiers for the observation. id_1 should definitely be unique in this data, but it's ok for id_2 to be NA for some rows. Eventually I will merge this data table with another data table using id_2. Does this context change your response at all?

Comment: Definitely! Sounds as though you want to include with higher priority the items with non-NA values for id2. What's now unclear is what to do with the values in rows that have no id2. Should those values be used to "fill in" the NA entries in the rows that have the fewest NA's? Should rows with id1's that are NA be removed? You should use the [edit] feature to clarify these issues and post an expanded example that demonstrates that possible patterns of missingness with multiple values of id1 and id2 and say what you need as an answer

Answer (score 0):

If the initial dataset is a `data.frame`, we can also try with `Reduce` in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[which.min(Reduce(`+`, lapply(.SD, is.na)))], id_1]
#   id_1 id_2 day month year
#1:    1    2 Mon   May 2017
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(id_1, id_2, day, month, year, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```